# Cassandra upgrade from 2.0.12.200 to 2.1.5.469 upgradesstables command seems stuck

Tags: cassandra, upgrade, datastax

As part of the upgrade of Datastax Entreprise from 4.6.1 to 4.7, I am upgrading Cassandra from 2.0.12.200 to 2.1.5.469. The overall DB size is about 27GB.

One step in the upgrade process is running `nodetool upgradesstables` on a seed node. However this command has been running for more than 48 hours now and looking at CPU and IO, this node seems to be effectively idle.

This is the current output from `nodetool compactionstats`. The numbers don't seem to change over the course of a few hours :

```
pending tasks: 28
compaction type        keyspace               table    completed         total    unit   progress
Upgrade sstables   prod_2_0_7_v1   image_event_index   8731948551   17452496604   bytes     50.03%
Upgrade sstables   prod_2_0_7_v1   image_event_index   9121634294   18710427035   bytes     48.75%
Active compaction remaining time :   0h00m00s
```

And this is the output from `nodetool netstats`:

```
Mode: NORMAL
Not sending any streams.
Read Repair Statistics:
Attempted: 0
Mismatch (Blocking): 0
Mismatch (Background): 0
Pool Name                    Active   Pending      Completed
Commands                        n/a         0              0
Responses                       n/a         0              0
```

My question is, is this normal behavior? Is there a way for me to check if this command is stuck or if it is actually still doing work?
If it is stuck, what's the best course of action?

For what it's worth this node is an M3-Large instance on Amazon EC2 with all the data on the local ephemeral disk (SSD).

Comment: Cassandra 2.1.5 to 2.1.7 have had quite a few bugs that might affect performance like this. I'd recommend not upgrading until 2.1.8 is released, which should fix quite a few of the issues.

Comment: Can you run some thread dumps and find out what the compaction executors are doing?

sudo su - cassandra -s /bin/bash

wget https://gist.githubusercontent.com/phact/22aa5085e58a43de7425/raw/de435ea127f1acde1054ad3c6af4995856e1a1be/threadDump.sh

wget https://gist.githubusercontent.com/phact/6c2699e884950acd2ed0/raw/688827d8f1c0fc882985394f2e1ee5be21bef804/topthreads.py

wget https://gist.githubusercontent.com/phact/22aa5085e58a43de7425/raw/de435ea127f1acde1054ad3c6af4995856e1a1be/threadDump.sh

export mypid=`cat /run/dse/dse.pid`

sudo chmod 777 threadDump.sh

./threadDump.sh $mypid 10 10

Comment: Then post jstack.out and top.out

Comment: @TomvanderWoerdt FYI, DSE builds of Cassandra include major fixes that have not made it into regular c* releases. Do you have a specific Jira that you think might be causing this?